# Convert assembly code from solc to binary code

Tags: solidity

I cannot find a proper option to compile assembly code that I generated from Solidity code (via ) into EVM bytecode. There is the flag for which I assumed to be the correct way to convert either the assembly code or the opcodes of my Solidity code into bytecode, but none of it worked. Unfortunately, I could not find much documentation on the mode either.

Does anybody know how to do this or where to find proper documentation on the topic?solc --asm--assemblesolc--assemble

Comment: solitity is a high level language and the tool generates asm, but I don't think it compiles asm. You can use `geth` or other assemblers to get evm bytecode from evm asm.